# How to solve recurrence $T(n) = T(\lceil{\frac{2n}{3}}\rceil)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion, trees, recursive-algorithms

I found a problem that gives recurrence relations as $$T(n) = 0 \qquad \text{for }n = 1$$$$T(n) = 1 \qquad \text{for }n = 2$$ $$T(n) = T(\lceil{\frac{2n}{3}}\rceil) \qquad \text{for n > 2}$$

Since we know $$\frac{2n}{3} \leqslant \lceil{\frac{2n}{3}}\rceil < \frac{2n}{3} + 1$$

I have tried to use two recursive tree to solve the recurrence. One tree divide $n$ to $\frac{2n}{3}$, while another tree divide $n$ to $\frac{2n}{3} + 1$. The first tree gives me the lower bound for $T(n)$, as the second tree gives me the upper bound for $T(n)$.

However, I don't know how to count the second tree. The size of the node in the second tree follows the pattern that 
$$(\frac{2}{3})^{l}n + (\frac{2}{3})^{l-1} + (\frac{2}{3})^{l-2} + \dots + (\frac{2}{3})^{0}$$

To find the height of that tree, I used geometric series as following:

$$\begin{align}
(\frac{2}{3})^{l}n + (\frac{2}{3})^{l-1} + (\frac{2}{3})^{l-2} + \dots + (\frac{2}{3})^{0} &= 2 \\
(\frac{2}{3})^{l}n + \frac{1 - (\frac{2}{3})^{l-1+1}}{1 - \frac{2}{3}} &= 2\\  (\frac{2}{3})^{l}n +3 -  3(\frac{2}{3})^{l}&= 2 \\ (\frac{2}{3})^{l}(n-3)&= -1 \\ l &= \log_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3-n}}\end{align}$$

It turns out that if $n > 3$, my tree height is undefined, which is what I don't want.

Can anyone point out what I did wrong, or give me some ideas of other solutions?

Any replies and answers are appreciated.

Comment: compute a few values of $T(n)$, you will find $T(3) = T(4) = T(5) = \cdots = 1$.

Comment: Iterating $n \rightarrow \dfrac{2n}{3} + 1$ can never take a number greater than 3 to a number below 3. Thus no solution for $l$ when $n > 3$.

Comment: @NeilW Oh I see, it makes sense. I have set the upper bound to high. Can you give me some ideas to find the upper bound of this recurrence relations?

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, but from a recurrence tree perspective, I have no operations until the leaf level (when the size hit 2). The number of leaves is not 1, so I am kinda confused... Can you give me some suggestions on how to solve this recurrence please?

Comment: @JayWong Well you could get an upper bound on the number of steps taken to reach 4, rather than 2. Then you know T(4)=T(3)=T(2), so add another 2 steps.